# How to overlay one div over another div without using position: absolute?

Tags: css, overlay, css-position, margin

I have two divs with two images:

```
<div id="div1">    

     <div id="div2">
         <img src="img1" />
    </div> 

    <img src="img2" /> 

</div>
```

Second one is some smaller than first. How can I put second image on first image without using

```
#div2{
    position: absolute;
}
```

I need to get [similar](http://jsfiddle.net/4w5Ln/7/) result but without using position absolute property;

The main issue is that there are a lot of other elements, in parent div, not only div2.

Comment: Its not possible to set the background on the div, and then place an image inside the div with the background?

Comment: It doesn't meter how will I put the background for div. I need to position them like on example, but without using `position: absolute` for any of divs.

Comment: @meep: that's a clever way as well yes.

Comment: @DmytroTsiniavsky: What's wrong with absolute positioning? What's the main reason you don't want to use it? We may help you with that as well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Negative margins

You can do lots with negative margins. I've created [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/QEuNU/4) with just two images without any divs.

```css
img {
    display: block;
}
.small {
    margin: -202px 0 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.small.top {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 0 -202px 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/300/300">
<img class="small" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/200">
And some text
<img class="small top" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/200">
<img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/300/300">
And some more text
```

Comment: @DmytroTsiniavsky: I've updated my example with one image overlapping at the bottom and the other at the top if you need to position it on a particular place.

Comment: Robert Koritnik's Negative Margins answer was excellent and sorted a complex condition I had a horizontal menu who's initial li used a border-bottom:4px to create a custom client requested effect. But onHover it moved background underlying elements. Negative margin-bottom solved the problem perfectly! Many thanks.

Comment: This is only viable if the contained element is the same size or smaller than its parent. Otherwise it will stretch its parent.

Comment: OMG. thank you so much. Using a mailing program that uses HTML to set up printing postage for envelopes. It cannot deal properly with absolute and relative positioning, so the only way for me to put items on top of other items is with this.

Answer (score 10):

My question to you is why must you do this WITHOUT

```
#div2 {
    position: absolute;
}
```

If the problem you are encountering is because it's absolute to the page and not the div then make sure #div1 has the following:

```
#div1 {
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: No, that wasn't the problem, but, nevertheless, +1 for reply.

Answer (score 3):

Its not a good approach to use negative margins. Especially when email templating, gmail reject negative margin and positions. So another way is

```
    <div class='wrapDiv'  style='width: 255px;'>
           <div class='divToComeUp' style='
                    float: left;
                    margin-top: 149px; width:100%;'>This text comes above the .innerDiv  
according to the amount of margin-top that you give</div>

           <div class='innerDiv' style='width:100%; height:600px'>
               Inner div Content
           </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Could you share another example please?

Comment: share your html

Answer (score 2):

You could nest `div2` inside `div1`:

```
<div id="div1">
    <img src="\img1.png" />

    <div id="div2">
        <img src="\img1.png" />
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't form my question fully correct at the first time. Divs are already nested. I've edited the question.